# Switching between different input methods phonetic vs typewriter in ibus preferences has no effect

Tags: 11.10, gnome, keyboard, locale

I use Ubuntu 11.10 and Gnome environment.

I am able to type documents
in Hindi by a method shown [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LL7icGNhIfI). I installed `ibus-m17n` and `ibus` packages and have enabled support for
Hindi language in *gnome-language-selector*.

I have following input methods enabled in the ibus preferences window:

- Hindi inscript (m17n)
- Hindi phonetic (m17n)
- Hindi itrans (m17n)
- Hindi remington (m17n)
- Hindi typewriter (m17n)

Here is a screenshot of that screen:

[image]

As you can see in this screenhot, these methods are available in the drop
down menu of ibus.

[image]

I open LibreOffice and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> so that I can type in Hindi and it works.

When the input method is off as in this screenshot

[image]

then I am able to type in Hindi with following kind of keyboard

```
/usr/share/m17n/hi-typewriter.mim
```

e.g. by pressing key  <kbd>H</kbd> the letter `प`   gets typed, which is the expected behavior.

Now the problem is selecting the method *phonetic*.

Pressing the key  <kbd>H</kbd> key results in `प` again, which is not expected. As
per my understanding the keymap for phonetic input method in this case is

```
/usr/share/m17n/hi-phonetic.mim
```

and given that input method phonetic is already selected  (with phonetic selection) upon pressing the <kbd>H</kbd> key `य` should get typed.

That means that selection of different input methods has no effect on typing.

So is ibus not working properly or did I miss something? How can I get the expected behavior when selecing different input methods in the ibus preference window?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but suspect this might be a ibus bug in Ubuntu.

Probably best to report it in launchpad and maybe try to test a later version of ibus.